# Isn't using `urllib2.install_opener` dangerous?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I am working on a project where it would be very handy if I could mock out `urlopen` during testing. Someone pointed out to me that this is possible (and easy) by mocking out an `opener` and using [`urllib2.install_opener`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.install_opener).

However, I'm concerned because of this note in the documentation:

> Install an OpenerDirector instance as the default global opener.

Doesn't this mean that my program could unexpectedly break if other code that I rely on is using `urlopen`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implications are exactly what you'd expect. All subsequent calls to `urllib2.urlopen` in your program, until your either exit or call `install_opener` again, will use your opener.

Whether that's "dangerous" depends on your use case. If there are other parts of your code that are using `urllib2.open` and you don't want them mocked, then yes, this is a bad idea, because they will be mocked.

In that case, you'll have to get the to-be-mocked code to call `my_opener.open` instead of `urllib2.open`. If you design your code to be tested, this should be easy. If you need to monkeypatch code after the fact, it's a little trickier, but there are all kinds of possibilities. For example, if you want to mock all calls in a given module, just replace `foomodule.urllib2 = my_opener` and set `my_opener.urlopen = my_opener.open`.

Comment: I understand that using `install_opener` is not the way to go for mocking, I'm just trying to understand the implications of using `install_opener` (hypothetically).

Comment: @NT3RP: OK, I've edited the answer in hopes of clarifying, but… what exactly did you not understand? You already know that it changes the "default global opener". That means exactly what it sounds like. Any call to `urlopen` in your program after that, including code you forgot you wrote or code you imported from elsewhere, will get that opener, until your program ends.